# pass a function as a parameter to .get method and execute later

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get JSON data using the jQuery's GET method. I tried to pass a function as a parameter to GET method and execute it after. As GET method can take function as a parameter, I tried to call a function, but getting an error. I guess i've understood concept wrong?

**HTML**:

```
<button class="euro">Euro</button>
```

**JavaScript** (Using jQuery library):

```
<script>

$(function() {
  $('button.euro').click(function() {
    $.get('http://api.fixer.io/latest', myfun(data));

    function myfun(data) {
      $('#output').text(data.rates.INR);
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Inside the $.get function, don't execute the function (by giving parenthesis).  Try this:  `$.get('http://api.fixer.io/latest', myfun);`

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason why you need to pass name function instead of anonymous?
Following construct will execute function after the call is completed.

```
$.get('http://api.fixer.io/latest', function(data){
   $('#output').text(data.rates.INR);
});
```

Also you can use .done(function(){}) to chain the functions.

Comment: I wanna pass named function because that function will be reused by other functions too

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is that you want to execute a **Callback Function**

A callback function is called after a async process is completed (such as getting data from the server)

You could just use a anonymous function to make life easier like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('button.euro').click(function() {
    $.get('http://api.fixer.io/latest', function(data){
      $('#output').text(data.rates.INR);
    });
  });
});
```

or if you insist to do it your way, by calling your function inside the callback

you can do:

```
$(function() {
  $('button.euro').click(function() {
    $.get('https://api.fixer.io/latest', function(data) {
       myfun(data)
    });
  });  
});

function myfun(data) {
   alert(data.rates.INR);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Concept is that: JavaScript is a asynchronous language. This means second function does not wait any other function(or process) to be complete. Event emitter emits process parallel and listens completed process to run....

Using callback functions (not readable code) is not good way which exist nowadays. Yo can write this part of code with Promises or with Generators. It depends of your taste. (http://blog.mgechev.com/2014/12/21/handling-asynchronous-calls-with-es6-javascript-generators/)